# Proper way to set up a release pipeline in Azure Devops for Python based Azure Function

Tags: python-3.x, bash, azure-devops, azure-functions, continuous-deployment

I've a working build pipeline in Azure Devops that essentially installs Python3.6, sets up a virtual environment (.env) and then executes all unit tests. It then uses  as its final step, a copy operation to move all files, including the virtual environment to a drop folder.

My problem arises from creating a release pipe. I am running a bash script for the release pipeline that essentially installs the azure functions command tools, and then I activate the python virtual environment before  I call the func azure publish instruction.

The error I get states that settings are encrypted and that I need to call func setting add to add settings, however, when run locally, the script executes without any error whatsoever.

Does anyone have a working release pipeline in Azure Devops for a python-based Azure Function that they'd be able to share with me, so I can perhaps see what I am doing wrong?

Here is the relevant bit of script that executes:

```bash
#!/usr/bin/env bash
FUNCTION_APP_NAME="secret"
FUNCTION_APP_FOLDER="evenMoreSecret"


# Install Azure Functions Core Tools
echo "--> Install Azure Functions Core Tools"
wget -q https://packages.microsoft.com/config/ubuntu/16.04/packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo dpkg -i packages-microsoft-prod.deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install azure-functions-core-tools -y

echo ">>>>>>>> Initialize Python Virtual Environment"
source .env/bin/activate

echo "--> Publish the function app to Azure Functions"
cd $FUNCTION_APP_FOLDER
func azure functionapp publish $FUNCTION_APP_NAME --build-native-deps
```

The script is executed using an Azure CLI, using a security principal which is tied to the azure account that it is targeting.

Comment: why dont use use native azure devops webapp step for that?

Comment: Because it is an Azure FunctionApp, not a WebApp, and there is no deployment step for  functions written in Python that I'm aware of.

Comment: there is no difference? it copies files over and runs deployment.cmd, at least thats what I thought?

Comment: There is no deployment.cmd. The azure function was created using the Azure Function core tools, it made the skeleton project in python without any deployment files. ,The way it is supposed to work, based on documentation, is to deploy using the azure function core tools as you see as the last line of the script above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer myself as I've solved the problem. 
To @Oliver Dolk: We do NOT want to publish as part of a build pipeline. The only thing I'm interested in is to set up a virtual environment and then run the unit tests.

The RELEASE stage is where we want to deploy the scripts copied over from the build step. These artifacts are then the basis for releasing into dev, test and prodution environment.

I was missing a very important step in my script; To create a local.settings.json file which contains encrypted settings for the functionapp.

In order to solve the problem, I only had to call the following:

```sh
func azure functionapp fetch-app-settings $FUNCTION_APP_NAME
```

This calls the azure functionApp, and retrieves it's settings into an encrypted local.settings.json which is then used during publishing.

For a complete script reference of both the build YAML script and the bash script that does the deployment, I've put both in an anonimized github repo:

https://github.com/digitaldias/Python-Examples

Answer (score 2):

Usually with Azure DevOps you create several build steps that result in some build artifacts - these are defined in the azure-pipelines.yml file. You then do a release step to release the artifacts that you have created - this is created within the UI. This can involve deploying to a test server and then to production or however you want to configure it. What you are describing is doing the build and release step all in the one yaml file as the func publish is essentially doing a release and it seems to all be in the one script.

In the next release of the az cli there is a new command called `az functionapp devops-build` that will set up the DevOps pipeline with the seperate build and release steps. However, in the mean time, we have created a series of beta yaml files that we hope you can just drag and drop to do the build and release steps just within the build part (as you are doing).

The beta yaml files are here:
https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-devops-build/wiki/Yaml-Samples

I must disclaim that they are not fully tested, nor are they supported yet.